# Why Use Nested Transaction In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

What is use of nested transaction in sql server.
As we know that there is no scope of inner transaction, if we committed inner transaction and rollback by outer transaction then outer transaction will rollback inner transaction so what is use of inner transaction

Please explain me.

Thanks - Girijesh Kuamr

Comment: That is a good question. I never understood this concept either.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and off-topic for this site.

Comment: You might want to study this excellent blog post: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) - the **syntax** is there - but the functionality really isn't ... at least not the way most developers would expect it..

Answer (score 6):

From Books Online :

> Explicit transactions can be nested. This is primarily intended to
>   support transactions in stored procedures that can be called either
>   from a process already in a transaction or from processes that have no
>   active transaction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: But upon rolling back or committing the outer transaction, the inner transactions' status will be ignored, which I think is the OP's question.

Comment: Think of a situation where you have two procs, A and B, both which begin a transaction.  If you call A, which calls B, then the transaction is ignored in B because it was started in A.  If you call B directly, it is not ignored.